# Sweeping over multiple configurations

Tags: python, hydra

I'm interested in using hydra to run some experiments over various datasets.  Following the documentation found [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/multi-run/#sweeping-via-hydrasweeperparams), I've set up my `conf` directory as follows

```
conf
├── config.yaml
├── dataset
│   ├── experiment_1_0.yaml
│   ├── experiment_2_0.yaml
│   ├── experiment_2_1.yaml
│   ├── experiment_3_0.yaml
│   ├── experiment_3_1.yaml
│   └── experiment_3_2.yaml
└── model
    ├── dummy.yaml
    └── naive_bayes.yaml
```

My `config.yaml` file looks like

```
defaults:
  - model: ???
  - dataset: ???
  - _self_

hydra:
  sweeper:
    params:
      model: glob(*)
      dataset: glob(*)
```

Running my `main.py` file using `python main.py` however yields the following error

```
You must specify 'dataset', e.g, dataset=<OPTION>
Available options:
        experiment_1_0
        experiment_2_0
        experiment_2_1
        experiment_3_0
        experiment_3_1
        experiment_3_2

Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.
```

Asking me to instead specify the dataset (and were I to do that it would ask me to specify the model).  I anticipate that there is a problem in the `config.yaml` file.  Are the `???` valid?  I believe I have followed the documentation closely, so how can I implement the sweep over the 12 configs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is to add the `--multirun` flag like

```
python main.py --multirun
```

and the experiments seem to run as expected